# Android DataBinding in RecyclerView.ViewHolders with different layouts

Tags: android, android-viewholder, android-databinding

I'm trying to use androids databinding feature in new project and so far very happy with it.

But now i came across a problem in my recyclerviews viewholder.

My viewholder uses different layouts (based on the viewtype when it gets created)

```
public MediaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
     switch(viewType){
          case HEADER: 
             int layout = R.layout.item_media_header;
             break;
          case DEFAULT: 
             int layout = R.layout.item_media_default;
             break;
          case SMALL: 
             int layout = R.layout.item_media_small;
             break;
     }
     View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout, parent, false);
     return new MediaViewHolder(v);
}
```

So all of those 3 layouts have the same views in it, only arranged differently. So the binding of the model to the views is the same.

Anyways, based on those layouts android creates

- ItemMediaHeaderBinding
- ItemMediaDefaultBinding
- ItemMediaSmallBinding

Which sucks since it would force me to create 3 different ViewHolder classes or instantiate the right binding Class by checking which layout is used.

Is there a best practice for this case? Is there a possibility to simply create a superclass for those three binding classes like "ItemMediaBinding".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what I ended up doing, was to create a `BaseViewHolder.class`, create other `ViewHolder` classes that extend this `BaseViewHolder`, so that my `RecyclerView.Adapter` still looks clean, because I ended up with something like this as a `ViewHolder`:

```
public class BaseVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ViewDataBinding mBinding;

    public BaseVH(ViewDataBinding mBinding) {
        super(mBinding.getRoot());
        this.mBinding = mBinding;
    }

    public void displayPost(final NewsItem post) {
        PostItemViewModel vm = new PostItemViewModel();
        vm.getPost().set(post);
        mBinding.setVariable(BR.viewModel, vm);
    }
}

public class TextPostVH extends BaseVH {
    private final PostTextBinding mBinding;

    public TextPostVH(final PostTextBinding binding) {
        super(binding);
        mBinding = binding;
    }

    //Have a method like this in the BaseVH.class
    @Override
    public void displayPost(final NewsItem post) {
        if (mBinding.getViewModel() == null) {
            mBinding.setViewModel(new PostItemViewModel());
        }
        mBinding.getViewModel().getPost().set(post);
    }
}
```

So you can simply call in the `onBindViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final BaseVH holder, final int position) {
    //only a ViewHolder containing ads has to be filtered, the others work with displayPost()
    if (holder instanceof AdVH){
        holder.displayPost(mPosts.get(position));
        ((AdVH) holder).displayAd();
    } else {
        holder.displayPost(mPosts.get(position));
    }
}
```

You can specify the `Binding class names` in your `layouts` in the `data`-tag:

```
 <data class="PostTextBinding" />
```

But I don't think that you are allowed to use the same class names in different layouts. You can find my (sample) project at [GitHub](https://github.com/amylinn/piqz).

Another solution is explained [here on Github](https://github.com/radzio/android-data-binding-recyclerview/blob/master/recyclerview-binding/src/main/java/net/droidlabs/mvvm/recyclerview/adapter/BindingRecyclerViewAdapter.java). They have created a (really) universal `RecyclerView.Adapter`, but I found this... a little too much for me at this moment.

Comment: thanks! i don't think it can get any cleaner with databinding and how its currently used.

Comment: Thank you. Learning this has costed me much, but I think it is totally worth it. :)

Answer (score 1):

@Amylinn is right, that really do for you, and you can make it even much easy:

```
// Only one ViewHolder at all
public class BaseVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ViewDataBinding mBinding;

    public BaseVH(ViewDataBinding mBinding) {
        super(mBinding.getRoot());
        this.mBinding = mBinding;
    }
    public ViewDataBinding() {
        return mBinding;
    }
}
```

In the `onBindViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final BaseVH holder, final int position) {
   // Just use "model" as name in any layouts
   holder.getBunding().setVariable(BR.model, mPosts.get(position));
}
```

But you still has to create view holder with different layout in `onCreateViewHolder`

Or if you like using delegate, you can look at this approach - https://github.com/drstranges/DataBinding_For_RecyclerView

Comment: This post has helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I write a library :The UniqueAdapter With DataBinding

[UniqueAdapter](https://github.com/captain-miao/UniqueAdapter)

just use the method:

```
public abstract boolean setVariable(int variableId, Object value);

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(holder instanceof UniqueViewHolder) {
        ItemModel item = getItem(position);
        UniqueViewHolder vh = ((UniqueViewHolder) holder);
        vh.dataBinding.setVariable(com.github.captain_miao.uniqueadapter.library.BR.viewModel, item);
        if (mPresenter != null) {
            vh.dataBinding.setVariable(com.github.captain_miao.uniqueadapter.library.BR.presenter, mPresenter);
        }
        vh.dataBinding.executePendingBindings();
    }
}
```